# -12 Volt Buck converter

Tags: buck, negative

I cant seem to figure this one out. Can someone please help me design a Buck converter that can take an input of around -40v and produce -12v around 2 amps?

Comment: This is actually a pretty good question, and, it's got an answer! You can turn a standard positive-side boost converter IC into a negative buck (and vice versa). The PWM switching sense and duty cycle favours that hack. The only thing you need to take care of is the feedback / sense input, which needs to be inverted. This can be done using a simple current mirror = two transistors, also involving some resistors for the feedback voltage divider (to set your output voltage). Synchronous-rectified version is absolutely possible. Google "negative buck" and browse the first two pages of results.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing can be done by a buck converter with a low side switch.

[image]

[ [Source](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/660) fig. 1 (a), also [here](http://www.powersystemsdesign.com/library/resources/images/Articles/Top_Story/May2012/) ]